# Is "sass --watch" used once per project or every time you are making changes?

Tags: command-line, sass

I am looking to start working with SASS/SCSS and want some clarification.

If I run the line `sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets` (per the site's example); do I have to type this into the command line every time I want to work on the project or just when starting up a project?

I don't know if this matters but I am developing on a Windows Machine.

Comment: Neither. It runs until you kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need this command running as long as you are making changes to your `scss` files and want them to compile to `css`. So yes, every time.

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you know if it will retroactively update things if I forget to turn it on before I make changes? Either way I could just save the file again, just needed to know if it's a concern.

Comment: Well it won't compile to `css` unless you run the command, so you will have changed `scss` files but unchanged `css` files, which defeats the whole purpose of sass :)

Comment: I understand that, what I was saying was: If I forget to start "watching" and I update scss will the css auto update when I start "watching" again? I know I could always just run `sass app/sass:public/stylesheets`, but why waste the time if it does it automatically.

Comment: Yes when you watch again, the `css` will be the compiled version of the latest `scss` files.